# How to fix "ibtool exited with code 1" error in vs2017 during compile time after mac agent connected

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have connected successfully vs2017 to mac agent .
but when I am trying to compile or run application I am getting this below error

## Error 1:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       2017-10-06 12:11:58.749 ibtoold[6529:336750] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-12121/InterfaceBuilderKit/Utilities/IBAbstractInterfaceBuilderPlatformToolManager.m:257
Details:  Failed to attach to Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool with error: Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa76bcc36a0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa76bcc2770 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to spawn Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool on SimDevice : IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x (D5D6EB02-05E7-458D-802C-96454000F087) : state={ Booted } deviceType={ SimDeviceType : com.apple.dt.Xcode.IBSimDeviceType.iPad-2x } runtime={ SimRuntime : 10.3.1 (14E8301) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-10-3 }, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to launch Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool via CoreSimulator spawn}}, NSLocalizedDescription=Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for further information., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool (-1) failed to launch}
Object:   
Method:   +_THREADSAFE_launchNewToolWithLaunchContext:executionContext:toolProxyClass:failureContext:requestingMethod:error:forReason:
Thread:   {number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2017-10-06 12:11:58.751 ibtoold[6529:336750] [MT] IBPlatformTool: *** Failed to launch tool with description  System content 2x for IBCocoaTouchFramework-NineOneAndLater: Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool. (Failure reason: Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool (-1) failed to launch): Failed to launch Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool via CoreSimulator spawn (Failure reason: Failed to spawn Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool on SimDevice : IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x (D5D6EB02-05E7-458D-802C-96454000F087) : state={ Booted } deviceType={ SimDeviceType : com.apple.dt.Xcode.IBSimDeviceType.iPad-2x } runtime={ SimRuntime : 10.3.1 (14E8301) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-10-3 }): The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory (Failure reason: No such file or directory)
2017-10-06 12:12:07.561 ibtoold[6529:336750] [MT] IBPlatformTool: Wrote failed marshalling request diagnostics to path: /var/folders/x8/tw4ystt14g3b181dqr__p_x40000gn/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2017-10-06_12-12-07_321000    XamrinIOS

## Error 2:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       ibtool exited with code 1   XamrinIOS

## Error 3:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Internal error. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and attach "/var/folders/x8/tw4ystt14g3b181dqr__p_x40000gn/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2017-10-06_12-12-07_321000". XamrinIOS

Comment: Were both of the VS2017 on PC and VS for Mac on your Mac up to date?

Comment: You are getting an error on Apple's `ibtool` (Please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool). Does Xcode properly run on the Mac? Is it a matching version for the version of Xamarin.iOS that you are using?